# ImportError: No module named flask_mysqldb ("from flask_mysqldb import MySQL")

Tags: python, flask, sqldb

I'm using python 3.10. I want to use MySQL database, but whenever I am trying to import the module it throws the error. I am using MAC OS. There are certain file for windows to import but I wasn't able to find solution for Mac OS.

> ImportError: No module named flask_mysqldb

```
from flask_mysqldb import MySQL
```

Comment: Have you `pip`-installed `flask-mysqldb`?

Answer (score 0):

do you have flask_mysqldb installed on your work environment? if not

- Create a virtual environment for your script using the command
- pip3 install virtualenv
- virtualenv "desired name for virtual environment"

2. install flask_mysqldb according to the documentation

- pip install flask-mysqldb.
- from flask import Flask
- from flask_mysqldb import MySQL

Reference: https://flask-mysqldb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/